# H264 not playing in ie wrks on ff and chrome flawlessly

Tags: html, h.264

```
<video src="./testh264.mp4" controls autoplay loop muted preload="auto" poster="demo.jpg" >
  HTML5 Video is required for this example
</video>
```

Works in Chrome and Firefox ie says invalid source what in the world am I missing ? I have Googled my brains out and no one has a simple answer

Comment: What IE version ? and also post the video somewhere online so we can test the validity of it.

Comment: 11 and I'm at wrk and they have us blocked from most stuff .  The file was converted using handbrake to a h264.

Comment: are you getting the ***HTML5 Video is required for this example*** message or just the poster and the video does not play ? Any errors in the console ?

Comment: Player comes up black with purple loading dots then says invalid source .

Comment: Html1423 malformed start tag attributes  should be separated by whitespace

Comment: what's the mime-type on IE11?

Comment: @joshrt24 does this work: https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fqx3tLLy/ in your IE ?

Comment: Gaby the fiddle works good.

Comment: Where do I find mime-type?

Comment: open the developer console, look for a net panel, reload the page, see the mime-type of the video transferred, check for `video/mp4`

Comment: The fiddle serves a h264 file. So since that works, the problem must be in your file, or the way it is served by your server.

Comment: For some reason I can't find mime type. I see a network panel in there but when refresh nothing loads in there

Comment: I loaded the fIle to mime.ritey.Com and it shows it as video/mp4

Comment: Is there any other way to get a simple stinking video to work in ie

Comment: Changed handbrake file  preset to android and now it works fine. Thanks